# How to let css selector exclude an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have a css style like this :

```
    input.validation-passed {border: 1px solid #00CC00; color : #000;}
```

The javascript validation framework I use will inject every input tag with a class="validation-passed" .For the elements like `<input type='text' />` ... , this is ok , but for `<input type='button' />` , I want this is not applied , how should I do this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
.validation-passed:not(input[type="button"]) {color:red;}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to mention that this is CSS3 syntax that may not be fully supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support IE6, you can use an attribute selector:

```
input[type="text"].validation-passed {border: 1px solid #00CC00; color : #000;}
```

Comment: +1 There's no IE6 CSS only way I know of to accomplish this anyway, no sense in worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks ,but I need to support IE6!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. But you can inject a little piece of javascript to parse your inputs and add the class `text-validation-passed` to all your `text` inputs with the class `validation-passed` (or remove the class from button input if you don't need it).